# Mongodb mapReduce no counting the number of emits

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am trying the following:

```
map = %Q{
      function() {            
          emit(this.ei, { second: this.se, amount: this.am });
      }
    }

    reduce = %Q{
      function(key, values) {

        var count = 0;
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          count++;
        });

       return { second: 0, amount: count }
      }
    }
```

Problem is count (amount) == 2! I have so many documents here. When "debugging" I noticed that sometimes 'value' is an array. could it be? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I'm preferring the aggregation pipeline for simple things like this.

You are quite right with your observation of value being an array sometimes and you can see this in the example here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/ (in the graph, blue is an array, grey is not).

Comment: This is what is expected indeed (having the reduce function receive VALUES as a form of array) - but from my example its something deeper. looks like a bug

Comment: nono, it's not a bug, it's always been annoying like that.